# What is a protocol for determining which of two numbers is larger, without sharing those numbers?

Tags: cryptography

**Situation**: Alice has selected a positive integer $a$, and Bob has selected a positive integer $b$. Alice and Bob want to know whether $a > b$, $a = b$, or $a < b$, but neither wishes to reveal their chosen number to the other party.

How can Alice and Bob make this determination?

Comment: Bidding? This smells of auctions.

Comment: Just a pointer to an answer at the moment, the problem is called ["Yao's Millionaire's Problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yao%27s_Millionaires%27_Problem) for which there is a protocol.

Comment: @LukeMathieson Ah, that's great, thanks! I'd seen this somewhere before and couldn't remember what the problem was called.

Comment: @LukeMathieson expand it to an answer ?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out [by Luke Mathieson in the comments](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18007/what-is-a-protocol-for-determining-which-of-two-numbers-is-larger-without-shari#comment36141_18007), this problem is called **Yao's Millionaire Problem**, for which protocols can easily be found by Googling.

Comment: I do not understand the problem well enough at this point to write a good answer for this question. If somebody does write a good answer (or really, any answer), I will unaccept this answer and accept that instead.